# How to update Microsoft Form responses when values in the corresponding spreadsheet are updated?

Tags: onedrive-for-business, microsoft-forms

**Desired Behaviour**

1. `Public User A` submits Microsoft Form which populates a connected spreadsheet in real time.
2. `Company Users` can edit responses within the connected spreadsheet.
3. The data presented in the `Responses` tab of the Microsoft Forms interface reflects the updated values.

**Current Behaviour**

Currently, after `Company Users` edit the spreadsheet, the data presented in the `Responses` tab of the Microsoft Forms interface displays the data *as it was originally entered*, rather than displaying the new values.

**Question**

How can I make the data presented in the `Responses` tab of the Microsoft Forms interface show the updated values from the connected spreadsheet, rather than the original values submitted?

**Steps To Replicate**

Create a form via:

`OneDrive file list` > `New` > `Forms for Excel`

This will forward you to the Microsoft Forms interface.

Click on the `Responses` tab and the `Open in Excel` link, which will created a spreadsheet where responses are added in real time.

Edit values in the responses in the connected spreadsheet.

Click on the `Responses` tab in the Microsoft Forms interface.

The data presented will reflect the values as they were originally entered, rather than the updated values.